# Missing configuration options on raspi-config screen??? No SPI or Device Tree

Tags: spi, raspi-config, device-tree

Downloaded NOOBS onto my SD card and got my RPi3 up and running.

I'm trying to enable Device Tree and SPI via the advanced options bit on the raspi-config blue screen (so i can install my 3.5inch waveshare screen) but my only options are:
A1 Expand filesystem
A2 Overscan
A3 Memory Split
A4 Audio
A5 Resolution
A6 GL Driver

How do I get the SPI and Device Tree options?

Comment: "There is no option to enable Device Tree. It is always enabled now." https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1257655&sid=a088f010b2b78ab5f14e22e747b8ff2b#p1257655

Answer (score 4):

> by scruss » Wed Feb 15, 2017 3:27 am
>
> **They're under ‘5 Interfacing Options’ now.**

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=174529